# Django:Getting List of values from query set

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following query

```
country=employees.objects.filter(manager_id__emp_id=111).values('emp_loc').distinct()
```

I get Output as `<QuerySet [{'emp_loc': 'IND'}, {'emp_loc': 'MLA'}]>`

But I need list

```
['IND','MLA']
```

How Can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `values_list` instead.

```
country=employees.objects.filter(manager_id__emp_id=111).values_list('emp_loc', flat=True).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative suggestion:

```
country = [ list(elem) for elem in list(employees.objects.filter(manager_id__emp_id=111).values_list('emp_loc', flat=True).distinct()]
```

Comment: Could you please provide some context as to how your solution works and why it might be better than others?